# Using gather_nd to build matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, vectorization

I am trying to construct the rank-2 `tf.float` tensor, `x`, from a rank-3 `tf.float` tensor, `y`, and rank-2 `tf.int32` tensor, `z` as:

`x[i][j] = y[i,z[i][j],j]`

I know that I need to use `tf.gather_nd` as:

```
x = tf.gather_nd(y,indices)
```

where

`indices[i][j][:] = [i,z[i][j],j]`

However, I am having trouble using tensorflow functions to essentially expand `z` into a higher-rank to construct `indices`.

I am trying to maintain these operations in a vectorized form.

Is it more practical to simply use `tf.stack` as,

`indices = tf.stack([ii,z,jj],axis=-1)`

where

`ii[i,:] = i`

and

`jj[:,j] = j`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you need:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Inputs
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None])
z = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None])
# Make first and last indices
y_shape = tf.shape(y)
ii, jj = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(y_shape[0]), tf.range(y_shape[2]), indexing='ij')
# Make full ND index
idx = tf.stack([ii, z, jj], axis=-1)
# Gather result
x = tf.gather_nd(y, idx)
# Test
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Numbers from 0 to 11 in a (3, 4) matrix
    a = np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4))
    # Make Y with replicas of the matrix multiplied by 1, 10 and 100
    y_val = np.stack([a, a * 10, a * 100], axis=1).astype(np.float32)
    # Z will be a (3, 4) matrix of values 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, ...
    z_val = (a % 3).astype(np.int32)
    # X  should have numbers from 0 to 11 multiplied by 1, 10, 100, 1, 10, 100, ...
    x_val = sess.run(x,  feed_dict={y: y_val, z: z_val}) #, feed_dict={y: y_val, z: z_val})
    print(x_val)
```

Output:

```
[[   0.   10.  200.    3.]
 [  40.  500.    6.   70.]
 [ 800.    9.  100. 1100.]]
```

Comment: Nice use of `tf.meshgrid.` I just used `tf.range` and broadcasted to construct the same thing.

Comment: @user18764 Yes, it's pretty much the same thing. Even though I have used `tf.meshgrid` several times I still forget about it sometimes and do it like that.